# Java: Constructing a class within an arraylist initialiser causes an error

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist

I've got a constructor that takes a parameter `ArrayList<Setting> settings`.

Now the problem is that I wrote the following call in a subclass:

```
super(new ArrayList<Setting>(){new Setting("", this, 0)});
```

This causes a lot of errors, the main one being `Invalid method declaration; return type required`, as well as `'{' or ';' expected`, `Parameter expected`, `Unexpected token` and `Constructor Setting() is never used`.

I tried switching to using regular arrays and it worked fine:

```
super(new Setting[]{new Setting("Exp Only", this, false)});
```

For now, I'm happy just using regular arrays, however I come across this error rather frequently, is there something I'm doing wrong or is this just the way it is, and if so, why?

Comment: Which java version are you using?

Comment: "*arraylist initialiser*"? in Java? can you point where you got that?

Comment: That isn't valid syntax, why do you think this is valid syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has introduced `of` method since java 9. You can use it as below.

```
super(List.of(new Setting("Exp Only", this, false)));
```

Comment: since java 9 of method is available.

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what I needed!